# Find column of largest entry

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help with the following function.

```
=COLUMN(LARGE(B6:F6,1))
```

I am trying to find the column number of the highest number in this array, but it always says:

> Argument must be a range.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to find the column number of the highest number in this array

try:

```
=MATCH(MAX(B6:F6); A6:F6; 0)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=MATCH(MAX(B6:F6); B6:F6; )+1
```